# Break command inside a while loop prevents second while loop from running

Tags: php

In this code, the first while loop just checks if the number of posts with a $message field available are more than one. If it is, the variable $morethanonce is defined, and break should exit the loop because it is no longer needed. Then the second while loop should execute.

But for some reason, the break in the first while loop is preventing the second while from running.

Of course, I can just remove the break, which is not strictly necessary, and everything works fine, but I would like someone to explain to me why this is happening.

```
<?php
function availability_warning () {
    global $post;
    $closed_messages_query = new WP_Query;
    $closed_messages_query->query('post_type=ok_product&showposts=50&orderby=title&order=ASC');
    $i = 0;
    while ($closed_messages_query->have_posts()) : $closed_messages_query->the_post();
        $message =  get_post_meta($post->ID, "ok_product_closed_message", true);    
        if ($message) {
            $i++;
            if ($i == 2){
                $morethanone = "yes";
                break;
            }
        }       
    endwhile;   
    $i = 0;
    while ($closed_messages_query->have_posts()) : $closed_messages_query->the_post();
        $message =  get_post_meta($post->ID, "ok_product_closed_message", true);    
        if ($message) { 
            $i++; 
            if ($i == 1) { 
                if ($morethanone == 'yes'){ echo '<div class="prod-warnings"><ul id="warnings" class="morethanone">';}
                else {echo '<div class="prod-warnings"><ul id="warnings">';}
            }
            echo '<li>'.$message.'</li>'; 
        }                  
    endwhile;
    if ($i > 0) { echo '</ul></div>'; } 
}

?>
```

Comment: maybe `$closed_messages_query->have_posts()` is returning false the second time around?

Comment: Could it be that you need to reset a $closed_messages_query->have_posts() pointer before your second while loop?

Comment: Could it be that you have only 1 or 2 posts only matching your query?

Comment: If I remove the break instruction, the second while runs properly, so it doesnt look like it has anything to do with the query, have_posts or the number of posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Your problem is not the break command.
The problem is the while condition. you use  "while ($closed_messages_query->have_posts())"
To use the same query in an additional loop you need to "rewind" the query, otherwise it will continue from the last row accessed.

Update: The loop usage seems wrong, if you want to continue using your code, at least put the line

```
$closed_messages_query->rewind_posts();
```

between the two loops under the first `endwhile;`

In any case your code is a bit too complicated, here is a small attempt at simplifying (can be even better refactored to better look and performance). I am not such a wordpress expert but here is my take (fixed per your comment)

```
<?php
function availability_warning () {
    global $post;
    $closed_messages_query = new WP_Query;
    $closed_messages_query->query('post_type=ok_product&showposts=50&orderby=title&order=ASC');

    if ( $closed_messages_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $i = 0;
        while ($closed_messages_query->have_posts()) : $closed_messages_query->the_post();
            $message =  get_post_meta($post->ID, "ok_product_closed_message", true);    
            if ($message) { 
                $i++;

                if ($i == 2)
                    echo '<div class="prod-warnings"><ul id="warnings" class="morethanone">';
                else
                    echo '<div class="prod-warnings"><ul id="warnings">';


                echo '<li>'.$message.'</li>'; 
            }                  
        endwhile;
        if ($i > 0) {
            echo '</ul></div>'; 
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Moshe, but that would not work. I want to check the quantity items matching the query AND having content in the ok_product_closed_message field. Your code only checks if there is more than one post matching the query. The solution would be to check this in the query, but this is a custom WP field and I dont think you can check those using WP_query. Anyway, I am sure there are much better ways to code this.

Comment: Also, my problem IS the break command. If I remove it, everything works as expected, including the query.

Comment: Fixed the code somewhat and added another small possible fix, please understand your use of the break is correct, the problem is with the flow of the code, in some cases the loop will continue from the place the break is, and in some cases the loop will restart (you have problems with the first scenario). I believe both solutions will fix it (you can modify my code to suite your needs of course - or give me some data (like the lists of posts you are working on and what output you are expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the **`break`** allows you to get out of the loop as soon as you have the expected data : no need to loop anymore *(that would not change anything to the result -- but would eat CPU for nothing)*

As to why you don't enter the second loop, I'm not sure *(I don't know the class you're using)*, but I would say that loading the data with `the_post()` probably makes some internal pointer advance, in the `$closed_messages_query` object.

And when that pointer has advanced enough, there will be no item left to loop over.

And you don't seem to re-initialize that *internal pointer* before the second loop.

Comment: OP's title is actually misleading. He knows what `break` does, he's wondering why the `break` in the first loop is stopping the second loop from running

Comment: @JohnP, exactly. If you have any suggestion for a better or cleare title please do say.